# How do I get post data using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have a CloudPage which I post to using form data, using SSJS I want to retrieve the `url` form input.

How can I do this?

Below you can find the code I have used but this doesn't appear to work, I've also tried variations like `postData.url` but this does not work either.

It should be noted `Platform.Request.GetPostData()` returns a string and not JSON.

```
<script runat=server language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");

  if (Request.Method == "POST") {
      // Handle post
      var postData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
      var jsonPost = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(postData);
      Write(Stringify(jsonPost.url));
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve form data using the following function in SSJS.

```
Platform.Request.GetFormField("attribute-here")
```

To retrieve the url form parameter you need to use `Platform.Request.GetFormField("url")`